# High Charts - Unable to populate series data via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

I am stuck up with a simple thing that is loading series data in Basic Bar using HighChart. I have returned the data using AJAX call, but problem is when data is returned, charts does not get loaded. But if I copy/paste my returned data in series it works perfectly fine.

Just to mention I am not using JSON Encode. I just made the string and echoed it. Below is what i actually wanted to achieve, my JS/HTML and returned string which I want to display

High Chart Example:

> http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

My Javascript and HTML

> http://jsfiddle.net/7c3gqwr9/

My Returned Data:

```
{name:'Total_Trans',data:[8798,88976,18564,8486]}, {name:'Sucesss',data:[6304,57642,8702,5202]}, {name:'MoreThan30',data:[208,1588,449,163]}, {name:'LessThan30',data:[8551,86864,18034,8290]}, {name:'NadraMoreThan30',data:[1535,4187,2634,1310]}, {name:'NadraLessThan30',data:[6024,66179,9812,5239]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your returned data is **not** JSON.

At the very least it needs to be within "[]" signs. Instead of

```
{name:'Total_Trans',data:[8798,88976,18564,8486]}, {name:'Sucesss'...,5239]}
```

you need to have

```
[{name:'Total_Trans',data:[8798,88976,18564,8486]}, {name:'Sucesss'...,5239]}]
```

Are you by any chance outputting several `json_encode()` from within a `foreach()`?

You should do:

```
$series = array();
foreach (...) {
     $series[] = array(
         'name'  => $record['name'], // "Hello world"
         'data'  => $data, // array(1,2,3,4);
     );
}
Header('Content-type: application/json');
die(json_encode($series));
```

If the data row is itself from another cycle, you need something like

```
$series = array();
foreach (...) {
     $data = array();
     foreach (...) {
         $data[] = $tuple['value'];
     }
     $series[] = array(
         'name'  => $record['name'], // "Hello world"
         'data'  => $data, // array(1,2,3,4);
     );
}
Header('Content-type: application/json');
die(json_encode($series));
```

You can declare your HighCharts chart normally, before invoking the AJAX. It will display an empty graph and you will have a HighCharts object. You can also do this inside the AJAX return function, but it's better to have the chart ready beforehand.

Then you can invoke the AJAX to fetch a block of data, **which still needs to be proper JSON** (there is no other easy way), and decode it:

```
var ch = $('#container').highcharts();
for (blk in jawad) {
    ch.addSeries(javad[blk]);
}
```

But to do this, your AJAX must return a proper JSON array with its correct MIME type too. If it returns a string, the whole setup simply won't work.

Comment: might sound stupid, but i had 6 arrays and i converted them to string using implode, here it goes "{name:'Total_Trans',data:[$totalTransactions]},{name:'Sucesss',data:[$Succeess]},{name:'MoreThan30',data:[$MoreThan30]},{name:'LessThan30',data:[$LessThan30]},{name:'NadraMoreThan30',data:[$NadraMoreThan30]},{name:'NadraLessThan30',data:[$NadraLessThan30]}");

Comment: Okay, that's the problem. Can you edit the question adding the arrays (two is enough)? You need to bundle them into one and code that. You *could* also output `'['.implode(',', $arrays).']'`, but it's a dirty fix and you risk trouble later on. Better go for `json_encode`.

Comment: i actually used implode, here is one example $MoreThan30 =  implode(",",$m);

Comment: I know its really nasty, but the query i had to work on had all data in columns and i had to use columns as rows :(

Comment: If you add the query and its output, I believe it can be converted to HighCharts format. I often have to do this kind of manipulation.

Comment: Can u suggest how to show that json in series, I am using chart.addSeries(data) but it aint working :/

Comment: In case when you have script which returns json, then (in javasript) you can use $.getJSON(), load data and initialise chart.